# How do I test a rejected Angular (1.6.1) promise in jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, promise, q

Below was my approach to testing rejected promises in angular 1.5.x. Updating to 1.6.1 has introduced the "Possibly unhandled rejection" error. I understand the purpose of this error, but I haven't figure out a simple way around it. Jasmine's (2.5.x) and.throwError() method seems to cause tests to fail by virtue of being an error.

```
describe('TestTarget', () => {
    let $q, $rootScope, TestTarget, SomeModel;

    beforeEach(() => {
        SomeModel = jasmine.createSpyObj('SomeModel', ['get']);

        module('something');
        module($provide => {
            $provide.value('SomeModel', SomeModel);
        });

        inject((_$q_, _$rootScope_, _TestTarget_) => {
            $q = _$q_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            TestTarget = _TestTarget_;
        });
    });

    describe('get()', () => {
        it('on error, adds a danger message', () => {
            SomeModel.get.and.returnValue($q.reject());
            // SomeModel.get.and.throwError(); // doesn't work either
            TestTarget.get();
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect(SomeModel.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(<< the rejection outcome of TestTarget.get().then() >>);
        });
    });
});
```

I want to continue to pass rejected promises across my models, services, and controllers.

Comment: It really depends on how you have implemented `TestTarget.get` but read my answer as an example which makes some assumptions about it

Answer (score 3):

Let us say your actual code is like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('TestTarget', ['SomeModel', function(SomeModel) {
    this.get = function() {
        return SomeModel.get();
    }
}]);
```

My assumption is you have no `.catch` block chained to the returning Promise. 
In this case you can simply test it like this:

```
it('on error, adds a danger message', () => {
    SomeModel.get.and.returnValue($q.reject('some error'));
    TestTarget.get()
        .then(function() {
            fail('the promise should not have been resolved');
        }).catch(function(err) {
            expect(err).toBe('some error');
        });
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(SomeModel.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Notice that I add a catch block to my function call. The `$rootScope.$digest()` makes sure that the promise is resolved and all its chained `then` and `catch` blocks are getting called.

Comment: This Works as expected, but what is the reason behind it to work? Anybody?? 
Because, as per the Jasmine documentation, returnValue and callFake should be same...

Comment: The difference is not between using `callFake` and `returnValue`. I guess it is due to putting expect in a guaranteed-to-be-async then block, vs. a sync block (and hoping Angular works out the async order).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with angular 1.6.1. Try callFake instead of returnValue in your test.

```
describe('TestTarget', () => {
let $q, $rootScope, TestTarget, SomeModel;

beforeEach(() => {
    SomeModel = jasmine.createSpyObj('SomeModel', ['get']);

    module('something');
    module($provide => {
        $provide.value('SomeModel', SomeModel);
    });

    inject((_$q_, _$rootScope_, _TestTarget_) => {
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        TestTarget = _TestTarget_;
    });
});

describe('get()', () => {
    it('on error, adds a danger message', () => {
        SomeModel.get.and.callFake(() => $q.reject());
        // SomeModel.get.and.throwError(); // doesn't work either
        TestTarget.get();
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(SomeModel.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(<< the rejection outcome of TestTarget.get().then() >>);
    });
});
```

});